# Utilizing an array value in a for loop for data frames

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column which represents customer name. I have made an ndarray with the customer names, and I trying to write a loop

```
for i in customer.values:
     print df[df[cust_name == i]]
```

But it gives me an error saying that the length should be the same. If I take a string value and assign it to i for one particular value, it works perfectly.

I also tried to change the I type to a string, but I get the same issue.
Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does your dataframe look like? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is `cust_name`?

Comment: The dataframe is sales data, including product, customer name, price, profit etc. cust_name is the column in the dataframe that has the customer name of type string

Comment: Type of i is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-abe4a3bdde47> in <module>()
      9 print(type(i))
     10 for i in old_cust.values:
---> 11     print (pricing_data[pricing_data['Local Customer '] == i])

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: How about some data and expected output? I want to see the contents of your column (5-10 rows) and the contents of i. Edit this into your question, I can't understand squat if you dump it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is going to sound stupid, but I rather do this now.
@COLDSPEED thank you for spending time on this and apologies for not framing a proper question.

But here is the error that I found. I created a dataframe by doing an inner join and called it old_cust

old_cust = pd.merge(old_cust, major_account_cust_2016,how='inner', on='Customer')

Then I was using a for loop with
for i in old_cust.values: and it gave me the value error

I just realized that print (type (old_cust.values)) give me  a class 'numpy.ndarray'

However, I should I have used print (type (old_cust.iloc[i]['Customer'])), as it give me class 'str' which I am using as

for i in range(len(old_cust)):
    print (pricing_data[pricing_data['Local Customer Level'] == old_cust.iloc[i]['Customer']])

and now it works. Again sorry for this, and thanks for spending time on this.